# Make new tmux session in IntelliJ separate from standalone Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to use my Oh-My-Zsh + tmux setup within IntelliJs embedded terminal, however whenever I open the terminal window I get a 'mirroring' effect on my standalone terminal which is also running like so:

[You can see that what I type on the IntelliJ terminal appears on my standalone one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HioM6.png)

Is there a way to create a new tmux session when the embedded terminal runs?

Ideally a non-IntelliJ specific fix would be ideal, I also experience this within VS Code.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If running `tmux` command (without arguments) automatically attach the existing session, maybe you have an alias on your `tmux` command like `alias tmux='tmux attach || tmux'`. Or check in your `.tmux.conf` if you have some weird configuration defined.

But generally, running `tmux new` or `tmux new-session` on another terminal will start a new session.